# Example of j-Interop Call to RTD or DDE Service

Tags: java, com, dde, rtd, j-interop

I'm looking to integrate quotes from the ThinkorSwim client provided by an RTD or DDE call.  The format of the calls if done from excel seems trivial enough:

```
=RTD("Tos.RTD", , "DELTA", ".NDX161216C3880")
```

OR

```
=DDE("TOS";"DELTA";".NDX161216C3920")
```

I've done quite a bit of searching on the web and can't seem to find an example of this type of call, although I have seem several posts that j-Interop would be a good tool for this requirement.  While I have a solid understanding of Java, my COM knowledge is pretty lacking and I'm having a hard time figuring out where to begin, specifically the parameters to use in establishing the connection to the server, making the request and then parsing the results.  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately, I went with PrettyTools  [link] (http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/) for DDE integration.  On my Windows 7 platform, there was a LOT of security configuration that I had to do locally in order to allow the DDE to communicate with ToS, but once configured, it works very well.

Comment: For those who might be interested, the main source of configuration updates to allow the DDE communication was actually from j-Interop at the following link: [link] (https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Config+Changes+needed+to+make+J-Interop+work#ConfigChangesneededtomakeJ-Interopwork-Shortsummaryofcommonproblems)

Comment: Java+COM is insane.  See ComfyJ and its licensing cost.  Best to create a microservice in C#, then query the service (HTTP/JSON/whatever) from Java.